# Debug vs Release behavior mystery in VC++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, undefined-behavior

For the program below, I get different results depending on whether I run it in Debug mode or Release mode in VC++ 6.0 on Windows 7.  Differences in Debug and Release behavior almost always indicates bugs in handling pointers and loops, but I cannot spot the bug.

In debug mode, I get the results I'm expecting:

```
Entered loop with i == 0, RecordCountNew == 0
RecordCountNew = 1 is positive.
Entered loop with i == 1, RecordCountNew == 1
Adding record with i == 1, RecordCountNew == 1
Added record with i == 1, RecordCountNew == 2
RecordCountNew = 3 is positive.
Entered loop with i == 2, RecordCountNew == 3
RecordCountNew = 4 is positive.
Finished loop with i == 3, RecordCountNew == 4
```

In Release mode, I get the same results, **except** for the assertion that RecordCountNew is positive:

```
Entered loop with i == 0, RecordCountNew == 0
RecordCountNew = 1 is positive.
Entered loop with i == 1, RecordCountNew == 1
Adding record with i == 1, RecordCountNew == 1
Added record with i == 1, RecordCountNew == 2
RecordCountNew = 3 is positive.
Entered loop with i == 2, RecordCountNew == 3
Finished loop with i == 3, RecordCountNew == 4
```

Can anyone replicate this on their machine, or better yet, explain it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct record {
    int ID;
};

int RecordLimit;
record* Records = NULL;
record** RecordIndex = NULL;
record** RecordIndexNew = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    RecordLimit = 10;
    Records = new (nothrow) record[RecordLimit];
    RecordIndex = new (nothrow) record*[RecordLimit];
    RecordIndexNew = new (nothrow) record*[RecordLimit];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < RecordLimit; i++) {
        RecordIndex[i] = NULL;
        RecordIndexNew[i] = NULL;
    }

    int RecordCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Records[i].ID = i;
        RecordCount++;
    }

    int RecordCountNew = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < RecordCount; i++) {

        printf("Entered loop with i == %d, RecordCountNew == %d\n", i, RecordCountNew);

        RecordIndexNew[RecordCountNew] = RecordIndex[i];

        bool AddNewRecord = (i == 1);

        if (AddNewRecord) {
            printf("Adding record with i == %d, RecordCountNew == %d\n", i, RecordCountNew);
            Records[RecordCount + (RecordCountNew - i)].ID = RecordCount + (RecordCountNew - i);
            RecordIndexNew[RecordCountNew + 1] = RecordIndexNew[RecordCountNew];
            RecordIndexNew[RecordCountNew] = &Records[RecordCount + (RecordCountNew - i)];
            RecordCountNew++;
            printf("Added record with i == %d, RecordCountNew == %d\n", i, RecordCountNew);
        }

        RecordCountNew++;
        if (RecordCountNew > 0) printf("RecordCountNew == %d is positive.\n", RecordCountNew);
    }

    printf("Finished loop with i == %d, RecordCountNew == %d\n", i, RecordCountNew);

    delete[] Records;
    delete[] RecordIndex;
    delete[] RecordIndexNew;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have VC 6.0 anymore, but it doesn't happen in VS2013. You could try debugging through it in release mode.

Comment: Why on earth are you still using VC 6.0?

Comment: I use Dev-C++ for release compiling, but find VC++ 6.0 convenient for debugging and noticed this discrepancy.  If there is a bug in VC++ 6.0 and not in the code, then I won't worry about it, but that's what I came here to determine.

Comment: If so, your question is misstated. What software you use for debugging is irrelevant. What counts is the compiler.  Are you saying the debut version came from VC6 and the release one came from Dev-C++?

Comment: No--I'm comparing VC++ 6.0 debug mode with VC++ 6.0 release mode.

Comment: Hmm, that's not what you said: "I use Dev-C++ **for release compiling**, but find VC++ 6.0 convenient for debugging"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The discrepancy I posted about **exists within VC++ 6.0 only**.  The "debugging" output is based on VC++ 6.0 in debugging mode and the "release" output is based on VC++ 6.0 in release mode.

Comment: I only brought up Dev-C++ in answer to Jonathan Potter's question, "Why on earth are you still using VC++ 6.0".  The answer to that is that I **don't** use it for final release compiling, but I like it for debugging.  I happened to compile the code in question in VC++ 6.0 release mode, too (there's no law against that, is there?) and noticed the discrepancy, which leads me to suspect there is a bug in the code.

Comment: (Correction replacing prior comment): Similar results in VC6++ SP6, but I get no "is positive" output at all. I'm going to take a look. We'll see if I can find anything. No promises.

Comment: Why do you use different systems for debugging and releasing? 'More convenient' isn't a justification for doing something as grossly invalid as this.nthe effect is that you will waste time, as you are here, on bugs that aren't present in the release version, and you run a major risk of not finding bugs that are present in the release version. Don't do this.

Comment: The optimized version is comparing (0>0)? instead of (RecordCountNew>0)?. This could be the result of an optimization bug (unlikely, even for VC6), or the result of Undefined Behavior (much more likely). I don't immediately see anything that looks like UB , but I might just be tired. It might help to understand what the code is trying to do, because it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: EJP, the only time that's being wasted is addressing tangential issues, like why I use the compilers I use.  But I am rather amused by your recommendation to just stick with a compiler that doesn't produce unpredictable behavior and assume that if the code works as expected on one tiny test case with one compiler, then all the other compilers are wrong the the code is good.

Comment: Euro Micelli, I also have SP6 installed.  One possible clue as to what's going on is that if the declarations of Records, RecordIndex and RecordIndexNew are moved into main(), then I get expected output in V6++ release mode.

Comment: The Dark, can you elaborate on what you mean by debugging in release mode?  I'm no pro, but when I debug in release mode, I do what I've done here: Strip the program down to the smallest chunk that exhibits unexpected output and insert printf's until the bug reveals itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Correction replacing prior comment): Similar results in VC6++ SP6,
>   but I get no "is positive" output at all. I'm going to take a look.
>   We'll see if I can find anything. No promises ( Euro Micelli )

I've replicated the same results (no ouptut at all on Release) @EuroMicelli found. However if you declare `RecordCountNew` as volatile, the outputs are present :

```
volatile int RecordCountNew = 0;
```

For your information, volatile is a keyword which tells the compiler that the variable can be modified externally at random times (during an CPU interruption for example) and prevent the compiler from aggressively optimizing the code around it.

**tldr** : the `MSVC6` has wrongly optimized out `RecordCountNew`.

PS : declaring `RecordCountNew` as `short` instead of `int` make the print outputs reappear. You never know what's going on in the brain of a 20 years old compiler.

PPS : since I'm asked to explain the bug, here is the disassembled version of a correct output :

[image]

the `edi` register store the `RecordCountNew` value and the `test` instruction command the jump to the `printf`. However, here is the OP's compiled version :

[image]

The `test` condition is being done on the base pointer register `ebp`, which has nothing to do with `RecordCountNew`. Depending on the value of `ebp`, the program output the line every time, or never.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever why you should need volatile on this variable. Marking the variable as volatile just prevents the compiler from applying most optimizations to it, so it's a cop-out / workaround. This doesn't answer the question of whether this is an optimizer bug or UB.

Comment: @EuroMicelli : it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Thank you documenting the details for all; it is well explained. This is the same exact thing I saw yesterday. My concern is that this doesn't prove it is an optimizer bug. The optimizer is allowed to output nonsensical assembler if the source code contains undefined behavior (UB). It's virtually impossible to distinguish between an optimization bug and the effects of UB by looking only at the assembler output. You either have to have intimate (insider?) knowledge of the optimizer, or you have to reason the source code and confirm it doesn't have UB.

Comment: That being said, I still don't see anything wrong with the source code, so I believe you are probably correct. I'd love for somebody to explain what the bug is.